# Multiple VBA If Or statements

Tags: vba, excel

I have 3 If statements that always result in true no matter the value of "dept".
If I remove two of the If statements leaving just one it works. What am I doing wrong?

```
Dim Dept As String
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ThisWorkbook


Dept = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Name, Sheet1.Range("F10"), 1)

If Dept = "Dept1" Or "Dept2" Then
wb.SendMail "email address", Subject:="Subject heading 1"

End If

If Dept = "Dept3" Or "Dept4" Then
wb.SendMail "email address", Subject:="Subject heading 2"

End If

If Dept = "Dept5" Or "Dept6" Then
wb.SendMail "email address", Subject:="Subject heading 3"

End If
```

Comment: I've been programming for > 20 years and just learned something new from you with that `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(...`. Didn't know the built in formula functions were available like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use Or like that here. You have to repeat the variable:

```
If Dept = "Dept1" Or Dept = "Dept2" Then
wb.SendMail "email address", Subject:="Subject heading 1"

End If

If Dept = "Dept3" Or Dept = "Dept4" Then
wb.SendMail "email address", Subject:="Subject heading 2"

End If

If Dept = "Dept5" Or Dept = "Dept6" Then
wb.SendMail "email address", Subject:="Subject heading 3"

End If
```

or you could use Select Case:

```
Select Case Dept
  case "Dept1", "Dept2"
wb.SendMail "email address", Subject:="Subject heading 1"
case "Dept3", "Dept4"
wb.SendMail "email address", Subject:="Subject heading 2"
case "Dept5", "Dept6"
wb.SendMail "email address", Subject:="Subject heading 3"

End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume `Dept` is a String variable.

Then the code should look like:

```
If Dept = "Dept1" Or Dept = "Dept2" Then
   wb.SendMail "email address", Subject:="Subject heading 1"
End If
```

VBA interprtates Your boolean Condition as
`(Dept = "Dept1") or CBool("Dept2")` VBA propably has a hard time converting Your String to a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding

```html
If Dept = "Dept1" Or Dept = "Dept2" Then
```

Probably since the Or is Dept, it is always true. All IF condition get executed